# Does iPhone have locale values for measurement units? Eg kg, lb and etc?

Tags: iphone, locale, units-of-measurement

I've searched the iPhone documentation and on google but have not found any information regarding locale values for preferred measurement units such as kg or lb and etc.

Does anyone know if this does exist? Or conversely NOT exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `NSLocaleMeasurementSystem` or `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem` key of the current locale.